# Rails: access associations within a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, models

To access a model's attributes within the model, you can call `self[:attribute_name]`, e.g. if you have a :question attribute then you can call `self[:question]` within the model to access the value for that attribute.

How can I do so for associations? When I try to access associations the same way it comes up as nil. So even though I can access `f.subs` outside the model, within the model `self[:subs]` comes up nil.

Thanks!

Comment: self refers to the singleton class of that particular object...you need to load it using self.includes(:accounts)... like this to access the associations as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try `self.subs` inside the model. if your method is instance method you can always called attributes and association using self.subs

`self.subs` will return you all assosiated objects against `self`(which is your current object. To get any attribute eg name of assosiated model.
you can simply try this

```
assosiated_obj = self.subs.first
p assosiated_obj.name
```

Comment: That's it! `self.subs` returned a type of `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` object, so I thought I couldn't use it. Thanks!